# Calque pairs like 'praeternatural/metaphysical'

Tags: etymology, vocabulary

There are words (not paired normally) which are, say, close relatives with (sometimes) totally different lives. For example, **praeternatural** = (*Lat.* praeter [beyond] + natura [nature]) and **metaphysical** = (*Gr.* meta [beyond] + phusis [nature]).

The both have different meanings, at the same time they are *calques* of each other.

Do you know of any other such pairs?

P. S.: It is interesting that in Russian one of such pairs has just been created within my generation: the word *прейскурант* (from German *Preiskurant*) had to make room in usage for the more recently introduced *прайс-лист* (from English *price list*).

**SUBMITTED PAIRS**:

*By myself*: **Praeternatural** (*Lat.* praeter [beyond] + natura [nature]) / **Metaphysical** (*Gr.* meta [beyond] + phusis [nature]).

*By Colin Fine*: **Adrenaline** (*Lat.* ad [to, near] + renal [of the kidneys]) / **Epinephrine** (*Gr.* epi [near] + nephros [kidneys]).

*By Janus Bahs Jacquet*:

1. **Aqua vitae** (*Lat.*) / **Whisk(e)y** (abbr. whiskebae/usquebaugh < *Irish* uisce beatha/ *Scottish* uisge beatha). *Water of life*.
2. **Vladimir** (*Slavic* vladi- [rule] + mir [world]) / **Henry** (*Germanic* heim(i)- [home, world] + rīkaz [rule]). *Ruler of the world*.

*By choster*: **Sarcophagus** (from Greek) / **Carnivore** (from Latin). Both stem from words meaning *flesh-eating*.

*By Fred2*: **Overman** (over + man) / **Superman** (*Lat.* super [over] + man). Coined to translate German *Übermensch*.

*By Merk:*

1. **Putsch** (*Swiss German* blow) / **Coup** (*Old French* blow), former meaning 'riot, revolt', the latter any sudden, decisive political act (popularly restricted to the overthrow of a government).
2. **Chirography (*Gr.*, chiros (hand) + graphe (which is written)) / **Manuscript** (*Latin*, manus (hand) + scriptus (which is written).

Comment: ‘Supernatural’ would be a third player in this set of calques, with simply a different prefix to translate _μετἀ_. While not really bilingual examples, pairs like ‘hyperbole’ and ‘metabol(ism)’ are also similar, in that words of different meanings are created from synonymous elements.

Comment: Sarcophagus/Carnivore? Torpedo/Narcosis? Periscope/Circumspect? But I suppose those wouldn't meet the strict definition of calque. This is a very interesting question, though.

Comment: Note that Aristotle's *Metaphysica* (*ta meta ta phusika*, "the [writings] after the physical [writings]") were simply the books that came *meta ta phusika*, "after the *Physica*", in the ordering of the Alexandrine canon. The meaning is not related to "beyond the physical". Artistotle's own title is *ta peri tês prôtês philosophias*, "the [writings] concerning first philosophy".

Comment: [PIE roots](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Grimmhandout.pdf) produces many doublets (like _grain/corn_ or _canine/hound_), or on occasion triplets (like _thermos/furnace/burn_) in English through words borrowed from various daughter languages. Since roughly half of English vocabulary is borrowed (mostly from Latin and French, with lots of Greek technical terms), just knowing [Grimm's Law](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/wow/grimm/) gives you a way to come within earshot of a paired borrowed word for many Germanic words. Of course you have to learn to distinguish them.

Comment: Note that ‘piranha’ has an alternative (and superior, if you ask me) etymology that holds that it is not from Tupí-Guaraní _piraña_ ‘scissors’ (< _pira_ ‘hair’ + _raim-_ ‘cutter’), but rather from Tupí-Guaraní _piráña_ ‘toothfish’ (< _pirá_ ‘fish’ + _aña_ ‘tooth’).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[**Eau-de-vie**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eau_de_vie) (< French *eau de vie* < Lat. *aqua vītae*)
and
[**Akvavit/aquavit**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akvavit) (< Scandiwegian *akvavit* < Lat. *aqua vītae*)
and
**whisk(e)y** (< abbr. ‘whiskebae’/‘usquebaugh’ < *uisce beatha* [Irish] / *uisge beatha* [Scottish])
— all types of locally important, strong alcoholic beverages meaning ‘water of life’.

**Vladimir** (< Slavic *vladi-* + *mir*¹)
and
**Henry** (< Germanic *heim(i)-* + *rīkaz*)
— ‘rule the world / ruler of the world’

**Benedict(ion)** (< Latin *bene* + *dict(iōn-)* < *dicō*)
and
**euphem(ism)** (< Greek *εὐ-* + *φήμη* < *φημί*)
‘well-speaking’ / ‘something well spoken’

(I’m sure there are many more, just can’t think of any off the top of my head)

---

¹ If we choose to believe that it is indeed from *mir*, rather than from **mēr* ‘greatness’.

Comment: **Aqua vitae** / **whiskey** is excellent and the most likely candidate to claim the fifty.

Comment: *Heimi* is rather *home*, while *mir* is indeed *world*, so this is a miss, though very close :)

Comment: _Heimi_ can mean both ‘home’ and ‘world’ in Common Germanic (in Old Norse and Modern Icelandic, for example, the noun nearly always means ‘world’, ‘home’ having a suffix: _heimili_). It is hard to tell whether one or the other meaning was intended in the name.

Comment: Looked that up and agree, so Henry and Vladimir are welcome (though not so excellent as the 'water of life' pair).

Comment: Just thought of a random parallel between the two: the _beatha_ ‘life’ part of the Irish and Scottish terms is etymologically closely related to _bith_, which means … ‘world’! (_Beatha_ is also an exact cognate to Latin _vīta_, but that is more incidental)

Answer (score 9):

How about *quintessence* and *Pentium*? They both mean "the fifth element".

**quintessence** (< Latin quint-us/a, fifth + essentia, (classical) element)

**Pentium** (< Greek pente, five + -ium, suffix for chemical elements, after the style of early-named elements like helium)

Answer (score 4):

**Melancholic** – gloomy [Greek *melanos*- black *khole*- bile]
**Atrabilious** – ill-natured, spiteful [Latin *atra*- black  *bilis*- bile]

**Magnanimous** [French *magnanimite* magnus- great *animus*- breath]
**Mahatma** [Sanskrit *maha-* great *atman-* breath]
Both literally meaning great-souled but with difference in application.

**Theodore**  [Greek god’s gift]
**Jonathan**  [Hebrew god gave]

**kamikaze** [Japanese
Kami (divine) kazi (wind)]
**typhoon** [Chinese Tai (great) fung (wind)]
[Reckless, destructive person or attack / violent storm]

Answer (score 3):

From least to most interesting:

**putsch** and **coup**

[does not meet the dual root critierion, but both mean 'slap'/'attack' in German and French respectively]

Also

**troika** and **trinity**

both with the roots 'three' + 'set of'

**preface** and **prologue**

preface: 1350–1400; Middle English prefas, which is from Old French preface (from which derives the modern French préface), from Medieval Latin prefatia, for classical Latin praefatio (“a saying beforehand”), from praefor (“to speak beforehand”), from prae- (“beforehand”) + for (“to speak”)

prologue: [from Latin prologus, from Greek prologos, from pro-2 + logos discourse]

**chirography** [handwriting, penmanship] and **manuscript**

[Greek hand + writing; Latin hand + writing]

**bacchanology** and **Festschrift**

bacchanology: The study of drinking and its preparations, and history.
(bacchanalia  = drunken feasts) + (logos = study/writing)

Festschrift: a volume of writings by different authors presented as a tribute or memorial especially to a scholar. German, from Fest celebration + Schrift writing

**kamikaze** and **spiritus sanctus**

[from Japanese, from kami divine + kaze wind, referring to the winds that, according to Japanese tradition, destroyed a Mongol invasion fleet in 1281]
[sanctus: consecrated, sacred, inviolable, venerable, august, divine, holy, pious, just; spiritus: breath, breathing; light breeze; spirit, ghost...]

Comment: Also: _prolegomenon_. The same as prologue, "to say beforehand." Rarely used, though.

Comment: I like ‘kamikaze’ and ‘spiritus sanctus’—never thought about that before! If one were more humorously inclined, of course, one might also argue that ‘kamikaze’ and ‘Budapest’ are parallels (though not with any proper etymology, of course): 神 _kami_ ‘god’ + 風邪 _kaze_ ‘common cold, disease’ = ‘Buddha’ (a kind of godish being) + ‘pest’. :-D

Comment: Perhaps add the definitions or links to "putsch" and "troika" for those like myself, who are clueless as their meanings?

Comment: I doubt whether _troika_ and _trinity_ meet the op requirements. They both really just mean threesome (as per the definition #1 in the American Heritage Dictionary). Some others are like that too. I thought the "totally different lives" was a must. But the kamikaze/spiritus sanctus has got to win some kind of a medal. The baddest entry yet.

Comment: If I were a persnickety fussbudget, which of course I'm naturally not of course, I would notice that only a couple of entries really meet the requirements, which are the following, as exemplified in the op: 1) both paired words need to have become part of English to the extent of having shed their exoticism; 2) their last derivational step, the one which English used for calquing, must not involve either the same language, or, if it does, the same words; 3) they both need to have gone on living different semantic English lives.

Comment: @Talia - 1) I think preternatural (and also OP's "ciseaux"!) is pretty exotic, but OK.  2) Only applies to one suggestion, preface/prologue, and doubtfully since both pro and logue are independent borrowings; similarly, the online etymology dictionary says sarcophagus was borrowed from Greek *through Latin*. 3) The core meaning of 'adrenaline' and 'epinephrine' are exactly the same.  Like prologue and trinity, adrenaline has additional extended uses that the other 'partner' does not.

Comment: Oooops. I didn't realize "ciseaux" was by OP himself. Yes, scratch (1). All of your other points taken too. OK,as you were. Study amongst yourselves.

Answer (score 3):

An interesting example, in that the meanings are *almost* the same except for a subtle distinction in usage, is **insectivorous** and **entomophagous** (and the related forms *insectivore*, *entomophagy*, *entomophage*, etc).

Both words refer to the consumption of insects. The difference is that an **insectivore** (Latin *insectum* + *vorare*) is an animal or plant that consumes insects, while **entomophagy** (Greek *entomon* + *phagein*) usually refers to the practice of *humans* consuming insects ([here](http://www.csmonitor.com/Science/2011/0222/Study-Eating-bugs-could-reduce-global-warming) is a typical example).

A few more usage notes: *Insectivorous* [is the more common term](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=entomophagous,insectivorous&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), and seems strictly applied to non-humans - or at least I can't find any source in which (modern) humans are described as insectivores. *Entomophagous*, on the other hand, is occasionally applied to animals - for example, see this article on [*entomophagous parasites*](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02371057).

Answer (score 3):

**witchcraft**  (German *wicce* - conjurer *kraft* - skill) - sorcery
and
**thaumaturgy** (Greek *thaumatos* - conjurer *ergos* - work) - magic

**Extempore** (Latin *ex-* out of *tempus-* time)
and
**anachronism** (Greek *ana-* against *kronos-* time)

**Metamorphosis** (Greek *meta*-beyond *morphos-* form -osis)
and
**Transformation** (Latin *trans-* across *formare-* form -ion)

**polyglot** (Greek *polys*-  *glossa*- tongue)
and
**multilingual** (Latin *multi*- *lingua*- tongue)

**Sinciput** (Latin *semi*- *caput*- head)
and
**Migraine** (Greek *hemi*- *kranion*- skull)

**Coup de foudre** ( French strike, blow; lightning) now meaning love at first sight
and
**Blitzkrieg** (German lightning; war, violence)

Comment: ‘Witchcraft’ is not from German, it is a native English word.

Comment: I was recently browsing a bookstore and came across this book which traces the etymology of this word. It is uncertain and pretty complex, which is why I presume standard dictionaries avoid it. Current opinion favours a PIE or prot-Germanic origin.

Comment: Germanic, yes—German, no. Both parts are definitely traceable back to Common Germanic, and the English word is not a loan word from German.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick contribution:

**Listless** <  Old English *lystan* "pleasure" + *-lēas* "devoid of"

**Anhedonic** < Greek *an-* "without" + *hēdonē* "pleasure"

Answer (score 2):

Insect (Latin) vs Entomology (Greek)

Adrenaline (from ad-renal, Latin) vs Epinephrine (from epi-nephros, Greek)

Comment: I'm gratefully accepting the both, with these comments: 1) the 'adrenaline/epinephrine' pair: technically Latin *ad-* is not an exact counterpart of Greek *epi-*; 2) the 'insect/entomology' pair: can you please edit it to make 'insectology/entomology'?

Comment: I don't know a word _insectology_.

Comment: Etymonline knows it: "Hybrid insectology (1766, from French insectologie, 1744) is not much used." (http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=entomology)

Comment: @Mykola, only just saw your first comment now. When used with the accusative, _ἐπὶ_ is actually quite a close match with _ad_ in Latin; Thucydides, for example, wrote of _ἡ ὁδὸς ἡ ἀπὸ τῶν Πυλῶν ἐπί τὸ Ποσειδώνιον”_.

Comment: Thank you, @Janus. I'm studying Koine Greek right now and yesterday's topic has been 'Prepositions' so now I see exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

A calque doesn't need to have a different meaning, but it must be a word-for-word or morpheme-by-morpheme or root-for-root translation of a word in another language.  This *might* alter the definition, but not necessarily.

Olde English:**Werewolf**:`"man" +"wolf"`

Greek:**Lycanthrope**:`"wolf"+"man"`

---

American:**Salary Man**

Japanese:**Sarariman**

---

American:**Watershed**

German:**Wasserscheide**

---

Chevorlet's sales of the Nova model of car tanked in South America because-->
American:**Nova**:`powerfully exploding star brighter than any other in the sky`

Spanish: **No va**:`does not go`

---

American:**Masterpiece**

German:**Meisterwerk**

---

American:**Handy**`helpful, skilled at repair & maintenance, close at hand when needed`

German:**Handy**`a cell phone`

---

American:**Discotech**`A nightclub that features music & dancing as the prime social activity`

French:**Discoteque**:`A record library`

---

American:**High School**

Spanish:**Escuela alta**`School high`

---

American:**Aerospace**

French:**Aérospatiale**

---

American:**Pants**`trousers, slacks, blue jeans`

English:**Pants**`underwear, breifs, boxers`

Comment: I think the OP understands what a *calque* is. The question specifically asks for cases where the meanings *do* differ.

Comment: Possibly, but I can't feel sure of the true desire without more clarification.

Comment: @choster:  Ciseaux (not even a borrowing as far as I can tell) and piranha are not calques, but OP seems to think they are...

Comment: @Merk: not anymore, I agree that the etymology differs from what EOD says.

Answer (score 2):

If you permit phrases used in English, how about *carte blanche*, *clean slate*, and *tabula rasa*. They all literally mean a blank slate or piece of paper for writing on. Metaphorically, they mean quite different things.

Comment: I believe that 'carte blanche' and 'tabula rasa' is standard English, so they count.

Answer (score 1):

What about overman and superman? They are both calques of Übermensch.